# How to show seperate google maps v3 in different FloatingPanes using dojo

Tags: google-maps, dojo

I'm trying to open up more than one dojox.layout.FloatingPane with different instances of a Google Map using the V3 API.  I can always get the first FloatingPane to display correctly with the map, but after the first one I can't add more.  I thought maybe I couldn't add more than one google map to the page, but I tried that and it worked.  I discovered that no matter how I put the first map on the page (weather via a direct div on the page or on a FloatingPane), I couldn't get a Floating Pane to show another map.

At the bottom is a sample page that exhibits this behavior.  The buttons on top are for a map with a Floating Pane -- if you click either one first you will see that map.  After you open the FloatingPane with a map you can click on the initialize button and the other maps will load properly on the divs on the page, but not another FloatingPane with a map.  If you click the initialize button first then you can't see any of the maps on the FloatingPane.

I would like to be able to show multiple FloatingPanes with different Map instances on the same page if possible.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
            .gMapDiv {
                width: 100%; height: 100%;
            }
            .gMapContainerDiv {
                /*width: 480px; height: 300px;*/
                width: 100%; height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">
            @import url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css");
            @import url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css");
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
            djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                for (var i=0 ; i<2 ; i++) {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.422834*(i+1), -99.091452);
                    var mapDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    mapDiv.className = "gMapDiv";
                    document.getElementById("mapContainer" + (i+1)).appendChild(mapDiv);
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 8,
                        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
                }
            }

            dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
            dojo.require("dojox.layout.FloatingPane");

            //dojo.addOnLoad(initialize);
            //dojo.addOnLoad(function(){dojo.parser.parse();});

            // adapted from code at: http:((lgrammel.blogspot.com/2009/05/google-map-in-dojo-floatingpane.html
            function createMapPane(nhId,mapDiv,title, x, y, width, height) {
                mapFloatingPane = new dojox.layout.FloatingPane({
                    title: title,
                    resizable: true,
                    dockable: false,
                    style: "position:absolute;top:"+y+";left:"+x+";width:"+width+"px;height:"+height+"px;visibility:hidden;",
                    content: mapDiv,
                    id: "mapFloatingPane" + nhId
                });

                // quick fix for positioning, does not seem necessary in source code
                // example (FloatingPane test), but was necessary with dojo bin and
                // Firefox 3.0.1 (for me issue still exists in 3.5.5)
                mapFloatingPane.domNode.style.left = x + "px";
                mapFloatingPane.domNode.style.top = y + "px";
                mapFloatingPane.resize({ 'w': width, 'h': height });

                //dojo.body().appendChild(mapFloatingPane.domNode);
                dojo.byId("mapPanesDiv").appendChild(mapFloatingPane.domNode);

                mapFloatingPane.startup();
                return mapFloatingPane;
            }

            function showGMapOnFloatingPane(lat,lng,title,x,y,nhid) {
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                var myOptions = {
                  zoom: 12,
                  center: myLatLng,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var mcDiv = document.createElement('div');
                mcDiv.className = "gMapContainerDiv";
                var mapDiv = document.createElement('div');
                mapDiv.className = "gMapDiv";
                mcDiv.appendChild(mapDiv);
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv,myOptions);

                var mapFloatingPane = createMapPane(nhid,mcDiv,title,100,50,484,326);
                mapFloatingPane.show();
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="tundra ">
        <div id="mapPanesDiv"></div>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" id="mapBtn1">
                        Rockefeller Center
                        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
                            showGMapOnFloatingPane(40.758229,-73.977749,"Rockefeller Center",20,100,1);
                        </script>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" id="mapBtn2">
                        Las Vegas
                        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
                            showGMapOnFloatingPane(36.135657,-115.172424,"Las Vegas",250,100,2);
                        </script>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" style="text-align:left;"><div id="mapContainer1" style="width: 480px; height: 300px;border: 2px solid blue;"></div></td>
                <td width="50%" style="text-align:right;"><div id="mapContainer2" style="width: 480px; height: 300px;border: 2px solid red;"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" id="initBtn">
                        Initialize the bordered maps in regular div (not in floating pane)
                        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
                            initialize();
                        </script>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to seangarner on the #dojo IRC channel on irc.freenode.net I have an answer.  I had to move the creation of the map object to after calling FloatingPane.show().  Here is the modified `showGMapOnFloatingPane` function:

```
  function showGMapOnFloatingPane(lat,lng,title,x,y,nhid) {
   var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
   var myOptions = {
     zoom: 12,
     center: myLatLng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

   var mcDiv = document.createElement('div');
   mcDiv.className = "gMapContainerDiv";
   var mapDiv = document.createElement('div');
   mapDiv.className = "gMapDiv";
   mcDiv.appendChild(mapDiv);

         var mapFloatingPane = createMapPane(nhid,mcDiv,title,100,50,484,326);
         mapFloatingPane.show();
         var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv,myOptions);
  }
```

Comment: I also want to note that the way it currently is, the FloatingPane may show beneath other items on the page until you click on it.  The way to fix this issue is to add the FloatingPane domNode to the body, which can be accomplished like this:

dojo.body().appendChild(mapFloatingPane.domNode);

Instead of how I had it, like this:

dojo.byId("mapPanesDiv").appendChild(mapFloatingPane.domNode);